# error 404 not found when trying to show post by category

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show post by category, for example if I click Tutorial category it will show all post with category tutorial. But I'm getting error 404 not found.

Route

```
Route::get('/tags/{tags}', 'PageController@post_tags');
```

Controller

```
public function post_tags(Tag $tags)
{
    $data = Post::where('tags', $tags)->get();
    return view('page.app', compact('data'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach($tags as $item)
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/tags/{{$item->tags}}">{{ $item->tags }}</a></li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

If my code is wrong, how is the right way to show post by category?
sorry about my bad english

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper database setup for `Post` and `Tags`; you should have a `Tag.php` model, a `Post.php` model, and a pivot table `post_tag`, then a relationship between `Post` and `Tag`: See how a `belongsToMany()` relationship works: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. I suspect your `posts.tags` column contains something like `tutorial,something,another`, which is going to cause you a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you are sending $data to frontend not $tags, so you access the data via $data variable.

```
@foreach($data as $item)
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/tags/{{$item->tags}}">{{ $item->tags }}</a></li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```